# Oracle equivalent of CROSS APPLY VALUES

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have a oracle table like

```
CREATE TABLE UnPivotMe (
    FirstName varchar2(255) NOT NULL, 
    LastName varchar2(255) NOT NULL,
    Question1 varchar2(1000) NOT NULL,
    Answer1 varchar2(1000) NOT NULL,
    Question2 varchar2(1000) NOT NULL,
    Answer2 varchar2(1000) NOT NULL,
    Question3 varchar2(1000) NOT NULL,
    Answer3 varchar2(1000) NOT NULL,
    Question4 varchar2(1000) NOT NULL,
    Answer4 varchar2(1000) NOT NULL,
    Question5 varchar2(1000) NOT NULL,
    Answer5 varchar2(1000) NOT NULL
    )
```

Table has some data like

```
INSERT INTO UnPivotMe VALUES
   ('Kenneth','Fisher','What is your first name?','Kenneth','What is your favorite color?','green','What do you do for a living?','Not much',
           'What is 2x3','6','Why?','Because'),
   ('Bob','Smith','What is your first name?','Robert','What is your favorite color?','blue','What is 4x7?','238',
           'What is 7x6','Life the Universe and Everything','Why?','Why not'),
   ('Jane','Doe','What is your first name?','John','What is your favorite color?','plaid','What do you do for a living?','Door to door salesman',
           'What is 3/4','.75','Why?','yes'),
   ('Prince','Charming','What is your first name?','George','What is your favorite color?','Orange','What do you do for a living?','Not much',
           'What is 1235x523','Yea right','Why?','no')
```

In SQL Server 2016 i can do

```
SELECT UnPivotMe.FirstName, UnPivotMe.LastName, 
        CrossApplied.Question, CrossApplied.Answer
FROM UnPivotMe
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (Question1, Answer1),
                    (Question2, Answer2),
                    (Question3, Answer3),
                    (Question4, Answer4),
                    (Question5, Answer5)) 
            CrossApplied (Question, Answer)
```

I know Oracle has a cross apply too but what about the values clause does Oracle have it ?

If not what's the oracle equivalent of it please.

I am on Oracle 12c

Comment: It would be better to ask a different question: "I have this input data, in these tables with these columns, of these data types, and I need an output that looks like this... In SQL Server I can achieve it with this query: ....  How would I do the same in Oracle?"  The first part, where you show the inputs, is present in your question, but the desired output can only be guessed, and only if we know enough SQL Server to understand your code. Why not show explicitly what output you need? Then you can decide if the Oracle solution is similar to your SQL Server or not, but that shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SELECT ... FROM dual` and `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT UnPivotMe.FirstName, UnPivotMe.LastName, 
        CrossApplied.Question, CrossApplied.Answer
FROM UnPivotMe
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT Question1 As Question, Answer1 As Answer FROM dual Union All
   SELECT Question2, Answer2 FROM dual Union All
   SELECT Question3, Answer3 FROM dual Union All
   SELECT Question4, Answer4 FROM dual Union All
   SELECT Question5, Answer5 From dual
) CrossApplied
;
```

---

But Oracle 11g/12c has a special query for unpivoting a table:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, 
       Question, Answer
FROM UnPivotMe
UNPIVOT (
    (Question, Answer) FOR  (q, a) 
    IN 
    ( (Question1, Answer1),(Question2, Answer2),
      (Question3, Answer3),(Question4, Answer4),
      (Question5, Answer5))
)
;
```

---

You can also use an old-fashioned, but simple unpivt query

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Question1 as Question, Answer1 As answer
FROM UnPivotMe UNION ALL
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Question2 , Answer2
FROM UnPivotMe UNION ALL
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Question3 , Answer3
FROM UnPivotMe UNION ALL
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Question4 , Answer4
FROM UnPivotMe UNION ALL
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Question5 , Answer5
FROM UnPivotMe
```